# Installing Hadoop tar file vs Cloudera VM on Ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, cloudera

I am complete beginner to Hadoop and I saw various posts on internet whics tells about installing Cloudera VM using VMWare. Recently I saw a youtube video which shows how to install hadoop on ubuntu by downloading hadoop tar file from Apache but they didn't install Cloudera VM. My Question is:

What is the difference between the two approach? Is there any benefit using one over the another?

I want to learn Hadoop by myself and looking for the best way/more adopted way to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera is "yet-another distribution of hadoop" You can think of basic Hadoop as  stock android in Nexus mobile phones and Cloudera Hadoop as androids in non-nexus phone. Its basically a custom built version.

Cloudera is more of a plug-and play version meaning you can [download the VM](http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-5.html) and start playing with Hadoop.

On, the other hand,Hadoop in Ubuntu is a **get your hands dirty** mode where you work on building your own hadoop.

***Personal Opinion*** - I suggest setting up your own Hadoop that helps better understanding of internals of Hadoop and the Hadoop learning activities that follow.

Hope it helps. Happy Hadooping!

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time playing with the Cloudera software and their Quickstart VM is good, until you start trying to e.g. add nodes. It was not designed to do that but when you have invested time using it it would be nice to use it as a basis for a real system.

So the next step would be to use CDH (Cloudera's 'proper' Hadoop) or Hortonworks version HDP or maybe even MapR (I've not used it).

CDH and HDP technologies have nice GUI features over basic Hadoop and are seemingly easier to setup. HOWEVER I spent a lot of time trying to get both CDH and HDP to work unsuccesfully.

They give red lights and cryptic messages when things go wrong and add a layer of obfuscation when trying to fix things. For example in plain hadoop you can easily change the configuration files but in CDH you can't access them directly you have to discover where Cloudera hides their various options.

If would recommend using plain hadoop unless you have a big organisation, lots of people and machines.

UPDATE: I have finally got HDP to work and it is really nice. Good Ambari GUi and you can use Zeppelin Notebooks to do fancy graphics.